# Recreating a circle from an image using a scatter plot

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, coordinates

I have the following image below:

[image]

I used the following code:

```
X=imread('circle.png');
[I,J] = find(X ==0);
scatter(I,J)
```

... to get the coordinates of a binary image (circle.png). I got the coordinates,  but when I plot those coordinates on a scatter plot, I get three circles instead of one.  Why is this happening?

Comment: Look at the size of `X`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is most likely RGB instead of binary.  This means that you have a **three**-dimensional matrix instead of a two-dimensional one where each slice represents the red, green or blue components of a pixel in your image.

Therefore, if you are using RGB images, the `J` coordinate will actually be the column-major coordinate if you slice into the second and third dimensions combined. As such, because your image is binary, simply extract any one of the channels and try it again.  For binary images, each RGB tuple will be either `(0,0,0)` or `(255,255,255)` in your case.

Therefore, try doing:

```
X=imread('circle.png');
[I,J] = find(X(:,:,1) == 0); %// Change
scatter(I,J)
```

By reading in the image directly from StackOverflow instead:

```
X = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/RbOPG.png');
```

... I get this image:

[image]